# How to get data from remote php website in android application

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

I want to get data from php remote website.I have a php file through which i want to import data in android application.
I am unable to get data...exception error occurred(only exception part is running).I am new with the android so Please help me to solve this problem.I shall be thankful to you.Impatiently waiting for help.Thanks in advance.Stay blessed....
**Here is my code.**

```
package com.example.androiddevelopers.my;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class Downloadweb extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String data = "";
            URL url ;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try{

                String postdata = URLEncoder.encode("Player Name","UTF-8")+"=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[1],"UTF-8");
                postdata += URLEncoder.encode("Player Role","UTF-8")+"=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[2],"UTF-8");
                 //url =new URL("http://localhost/ODI-Team/ODI.php");

                url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(postdata);
                wr.flush();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int ch = reader.read();

                while(ch != -1){

                    char current=(char)ch;
                    data += current;
                    ch=reader.read();
                }
                return  data;
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error occured"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return "Error ocured"+e.getMessage();
            }

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
            try{
                webView.loadData(s,"text/html","UTF-8");
            }
            catch (Exception e){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        try{

            Downloadweb downloadweb=new Downloadweb();
            //replace with your own laptop ip address
            downloadweb.execute(new String[]{"http://192.168.0.109/ODI.php"});
        }
        catch (Exception e){

            //Toast.makeText(this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            webView.loadData("<html><body>Error Occured.</body></html>","text/html","UTF-8");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception and also do you want data from php website or php webservice ?

Comment: error occurred length=1;index=1 this is the exception.I had developed a project in R and the result are saved in csv file then i am getting the result in php file and now i want these result to android application

Comment: You might be having index out of bound exception. As you are only passing a single parameter to your asynctask while you are trying to access 1 and 2 index element from the asynctask array. in your url encoding code

Comment: Sir can i have your email or whatsapp number?

Comment: No.Why can't you ask here.Here you have thousands of developers, why you want to get restricted to only me.

Comment: i just want help to get out of this..

Comment: Ask it here, I am already helping you.

Comment: thanks for the help bro but still am getting the same error

Comment: update your code in the question to show what you changed

Comment: Post the exception that you are getting.

Comment: length=1; index=1.....is the exception

Comment: `params[1]`,`params[2]`,`downloadweb.execute(new String[]{"http://192.168.0.109/ODI.php"});` here's your problem. You have only params[0] in your asynctask, 1 and 2 throws `IndexOfBoundsException`. Try to pass something more except server url only.

Comment: Sir i had a php file i want to get data from that into android.192.168.0.109 is the ip address of my laptop and the file is odi.php and i want to get odi.php data in my android app

Answer (score 0):

Man, `protected String doInBackground(String... params)` - this method perform operations on a background thread. `String... params` - it's a string array with parameters, which you'll passing to the this thread. `.execute()` - here you are executing asynctask with parameters passed to the background thread, but there is only one argument `"http://192.168.0.109/ODI.php"`, but in your doInBackground() method you are trying to get `"Player Name"` and `Player Role` from argument, which doesn't exist. Here you have what I mean.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) { // <--- in yor case params contains only 1 element with index 0

    ...

    String postdata = URLEncoder.encode("Player Name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[1], "UTF-8"); // here's your second execute params, it's error
    postdata += URLEncoder.encode("Player Role", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[2], "UTF-8"); // here's your third execute params, it's error

    url = new URL(params[0]); // here's your first execute params
}
```

And in activty

```
Downloadweb downloadweb = new Downloadweb();
    //replace with your own laptop ip address
    downloadweb.execute(new String[] {
                    "http://192.168.0.109/ODI.php", // <--- its params[0]
                    "", // <--- here's your missing params[1]
                    "" // <--- here's your missing params[2]
            });
```

That's all, why you are getting an error.

[Here's](https://alvinalexander.com/android/asynctask-examples-parameters-callbacks-executing-canceling) you have some docs, how using asynctask with examples.


@Edit

I'm using BufferedReader for fetching string from remote server

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

    response.append(line + '\n');
    }
    rd.close();

    return response.toString();
```

Comment: bro when i remove the param 1 and 2 there comes an error in wr.write();...so what should i write in parenthesis

Comment: Sir can i have your gmail or whatsapp no?

Comment: I think there is no any reason for this. If your code contains something, what you no want to share, just create some fake data.